# How to fix this error message related to library(forecast)

Tags: r

When executing `library(forecast)` in R I get this message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    no package named ‘quadprog’ is found